# The folders I deleted in android studio come back

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know what file they are but i think they are related to android studio they come back when i delete accidentally i installed the .android folder directly in the directory i gave it another way from sdk manager but how do i solve this problem? I try to what ı know but i cant

1. I try to change system environments path
2. Restart my pc

[image: error image]

**UPDATE**

The problem wasn't caused by android studio

**UPDATE**

Folder Content . All folders like that

[image: file content]

Answer (score 0):

It possible looks like the .git folder of a git repository or some kind other cache / object storage.

The easiest attempt to resolve this and to check if it's android studio causing this is to uninstall Android Studio. Remove all files. Remove the .android folder in your home directory. Remove (if present) the android sdk from `%localappdata%\Android` and the `.AndroidStudio*` folder from your user directory.

Then reinstall Android Studio

You can and should of course take backups from the settings if you want to.

Comment: @ErbayMavzer in these folders are probably some files, can you look at one of the files or possible upload one of them? But since the problem isn't from Android Studio it's probably off-topic for Stackoverflow now...